# Generating XML file from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to generate a XML file from SQL query and I have a table that contains following columns:

```
ItemNumber, Price, DateFrom, DateTo
```

The code I use to generate the XML is:

```
SELECT
    ItemNumber AS '@ItemNumber',
    Price AS '@Price',
    DateFrom AS 'DateFrom',
    DateTo AS 'DateTo'
FROM 
    #tempXML
FOR XML PATH('Item')
```

what I expect to get is something like this:

```
<Item id="111">
    <ItemNumber>111</ItemNumber>
        <Price value="3000">
            <DateFrom>2018-01-02</DateFrom>
            <DateTo>2018-01-30</DateTo>
        </Price>
        <Price value="2500">
            <DateFrom>2018-01-31</DateFrom>
            <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
        </Price>
 </Item>
 <Item>
    <ItemNumber>120</ItemNumber>
        <Price value="4000">
            <DateFrom>2018-01-12</DateFrom>
            <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
        </Price>
 </Item>
```

but instead I get something more like this:

```
<Item ItemNumber="111" Price="3000">
    <DateFrom>2018-01-02</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2018-01-30</DateTo>
</Item>
<Item ItemNumber="111" Price="2500">
    <DateFrom>2018-01-31</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
</Item>
<Item ItemNumber="120" Price="4000">
    <DateFrom>2018-01-12</DateFrom>
    <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
</Item>
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

[Sample data from the table I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o64x8.png)

```
CREATE TABLE #tempXML
(
    ItemNumber INT,
    Price INT,
    DateFrom DATE,
    DateTo DATE
)

INSERT INTO #tempXML
VALUES
    (111, 3000, '2018-01-02', '2018-01-30'),
    (111, 2500, '2018-01-31', '2018-11-22'),
    (120, 4000, '2018-01-12', '2018-11-22')
```

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0602/1

Comment: Where is `ItemNumber ` coming from? That's not in your table's definition that you provide. Could you also provide sample data that isn't xml (i.e. is in the format your data is actually currently in). thanks.

Comment: ItemNumber is a column in the #tempXML table, updated the question. Also added the data sample screen @Larnu

Comment: That's a weblink to an image, please supply the sample data as `text`, or (even better), as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Added to the question @Larnu

Comment: great, thanks. this gives us something much better to work with. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify how elements should be nested like this:

```
SELECT
ItemNumber AS '@id',
ItemNumber AS 'ItemNumber',
Price AS 'Price/@value',
DateFrom AS 'Price/DateFrom',
DateTo AS 'Price/DateTo'
FROM 
#tempXML
FOR XML PATH('Item');
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/columns-with-a-name?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is close, but isn't quite what the OP is after. If you look, you'll notice the OP only has one node for `Item id="111"`, which contains multiple `Price` nodes. This will produce 2 `Item id="111"` nodes, each with it own nodes for `Price`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be what you are after, however, it is a little messy:

```
SELECT T.ItemNumber AS [@ID],
       (SELECT T.ItemNumber,
               (SELECT sq.Price AS [@value],
                       (SELECT sq.DateFrom,
                               sq.DateTo
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                FROM #tempXML sq
                WHERE sq.ItemNumber = T.ItemNumber
                FOR XML PATH('Price'),TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
FROM #tempXML T
GROUP BY ItemNumber
FOR XML PATH ('Item');
```

This results in:

```
<Item ID="111">
    <ItemNumber>111</ItemNumber>
    <Price value="3000">
        <DateFrom>2018-01-02</DateFrom>
        <DateTo>2018-01-30</DateTo>
    </Price>
    <Price value="2500">
        <DateFrom>2018-01-31</DateFrom>
        <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
    </Price>
</Item>
<Item ID="120">
    <ItemNumber>120</ItemNumber>
    <Price value="4000">
        <DateFrom>2018-01-12</DateFrom>
        <DateTo>2018-11-22</DateTo>
    </Price>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more suggestion, a bit simpler...

```
SELECT t1.ItemNumber AS [@id]
      ,t1.ItemNumber
      ,(
        SELECT t2.Price AS [@value]
              ,t2.DateFrom
              ,t2.DateTo
        FROM #tempXML t2
        WHERE t1.ItemNumber=t2.ItemNumber
        FOR XML PATH('Price'),TYPE
       )

FROM #tempXML t1
GROUP BY t1.ItemNumber
FOR XML PATH('Item');
```

Some explanantion:

The `GROUP BY` will reduce the outer `SELECT` to *one-row-per-ItemNumber*, while the *sub-select* will act as a *correlated sub-query* and fetch all price-details for the given Item.